# Is there a less verbose way to get the commit date of the merge-base of origin/master and HEAD?

Tags: git, bash, git-log

The command I'm using to get the commit date of the merge-base of origin/master and HEAD is:

`git log "$(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)" -1 --pretty=tformat:%ci`

Is there a less verbose way to get this?

Comment: That doesn't seem crazy verbose to me...it's a fairly specific command, after all. If you find yourself needing this often, make a script or alias for it.

Comment: You can now shorten `HEAD` to `@`, and if `origin/master` is the upstream you can shorten that to `@{u}`, but as nneonneo said you might as well just make a git or shell alias or script for it.